# read input in primefaces notificationbar

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm trying to read an inputText which is placed in a p:notificationBar but I only get null as the input of it. The jsf code is :

```
    <h:form>
    <p:notificationBar position="top" 
                       effect="slide" 
                       styleClass="top" 
                       id="notificationPanel"
                       widgetVar="bar" >
            <h3>Subscribe</h3>
            Add your email adress here
            <h:panelGrid columns="3" cellspacing="20">
                Email:
                <p:inputText value="#{detailsBean.email}" />
                <p:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{detailsBean.submitEmail}" onclick="bar.hide()"/>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </p:notificationBar>  
    </h:form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML representation of the `<p:notificationBar>` will be relocated to the desired location in the HTML DOM tree and will in your particular case thus not end up in a HTML form anymore.

You need to move the `<h:form>` to inside the `<p:notificationBar>`.

```
<p:notificationBar position="top" 
                   effect="slide" 
                   styleClass="top" 
                   id="notificationPanel"
                   widgetVar="bar" >
    <h:form>
        <h3>Subscribe</h3>
        Add your email adress here
        <h:panelGrid columns="3" cellspacing="20">
            Email:
            <p:inputText value="#{detailsBean.email}" />
            <p:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{detailsBean.submitEmail}" onclick="bar.hide()"/>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
</p:notificationBar>
```